# View.isInEditMode() statically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI in my app. In Java classes which need native things I load the native library like so:

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("nativeegl");
}
```

To be honest I don't know what the static thing does exactly, but I guess this is to make sure that the `nativeegl` library is loaded before anything else. Don't remember where I got this pattern from.

Now if this is a `View` subclass, and I'm using the graphical editor in Android Studio, the editor can't load the view subclass because of this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nativeegl in java.library.path
```

Since `View.isInEditMode()` is an instance method, I can't use it within the `static{}` block.

Is there an alternative? Maybe I can load the library differently?

Comment: "Is there an alternative?" -- not that I am aware of. There are limits as to what the preview tools will support. This should not stop you from writing your Android code, but it does stop you from using the drag-and-drop GUI builder.

Comment: yea... commenting out the static block when using the editor does the trick for now *shrugs*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I think about it, one possible workaround is to split your `View` code into two classes: the actual `View`, and a separate standalone class that contains your JNI code, including the `static` block. For the purposes of the rest of this answer, I'll call these `FooView` and `BarWrapper`, respectively.

Then, only reference `BarWrapper` from code in `FooView` that is inside an `if (isInEditMode())` block.

This may prevent `BarWrapper` from being loaded by the Java/pseudoAndroid environment used by the GUI builder, and therefore not trigger the attempt to load your native library. Leastways, the Dalvik classloading rules would cause `BarWrapper` to be ignored, as classes only get loaded when they are first used, and in your case you would be skipping over all code that uses `BarWrapper`. Hopefully, the GUI builder code adheres to how Dalvik handles it, though that's far from assured, since it's running on a Java VM, not an Android VM (Dalvik or ART).

It may make your code a bit more clunky, as you have to split out your logic between two classes instead of just one. But, it may be worth an experiment.